# Unable to local MySQL database with Spring app deployed through Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm trying to create a web application using Spring and Hibernate, deploying it through Tomcat 8. I've setup MySQL and Tomcat 8 locally on my machine, and am able to deploy the web application to it. The app fails to launch due to the application/tomcat failing to connect to the database.

I'm following the setup tutorial here (Using Hibernate 4): [Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4)

When I try to deploy the application I receive the following error, which I abbreviated to the first error that occurred:

```
2015-07-27 20:42:46.768  INFO 77092 --- [n(11)-127.0.0.1] o.h.s.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator  : HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
2015-07-27 20:42:46.794  WARN 77092 --- [n(11)-127.0.0.1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
27-Jul-2015 20:42:46.793 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(11)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2247)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:484)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:142)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:51)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298)
... 95 more
```

**Application Setup (spring.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/myDatabase" />
    <property name="username" value="Root" />
    <property name="password" value="Root" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.journaldev.model.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="userDAO" class="fionn.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I tried following the suggestion outlined here: [Suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

It seems to be a problem with the database setup, as I am unable to ping it through terminal. Although I can login to it:

### MySQL Checks

**Login:**

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 

mysql> USE myDatabase
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_gofeisda_fionn |
+--------------------------+
| User                     |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MySQL Timeout:**

```
mysql> show global variables like '%timeout%';
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value             |
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| connect_timeout                 | 10                |
| delayed_insert_timeout          | 300               |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout     | 1                 |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF               |
| interactive_timeout             | 28800             |
| lock_wait_timeout               | 31536000          |
| net_read_timeout                | 30                |
| net_write_timeout               | 60                |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout          | 31536000          |
| slave_net_timeout               | 3600              |
| slow_launch_time                | 2                 |
| wait_timeout                    | 28800             |
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Check MySQL Timeout:**

```
mysql> show global variables like '%network%';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| skip_networking | OFF   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Check MySQL host:**

```
mysql> select user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Check MySQL Port**

```
mysql> show variables like '%port%';
+---------------------+-------+
| Variable_name       | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| innodb_support_xa   | ON    |
| large_files_support | ON    |
| port                | 3307  |
| report_host         |       |
| report_password     |       |
| report_port         | 3307  |
| report_user         |       |
+---------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Check Skip Networking**

```
mysql> show global variables like '%skip%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| skip_external_locking  | ON    |
| skip_name_resolve      | OFF   |
| skip_networking        | OFF   |
| skip_show_database     | OFF   |
| slave_skip_errors      | OFF   |
| sql_slave_skip_counter | 0     |
+------------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Ping Checks

**127.0.0.1**

```
$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.194 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.216 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.079/0.171/0.216/0.045 ms
```

**localhost**

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.202 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.222 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.054/0.121/0.222/0.068 ms
```

**localhost MySQL port**

```
$ ping localhost:3307
PING localhost:3307 (198.105.254.228): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
^C
--- localhost:3307 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

What else do I need to make sure that the database / tomcat / application are set up properly.

**Update 1:**

Following the instructions outlined here: [setup](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366143,376017#msg-376017)

I added the bind address parameter to the configuration file using 127.0.0.1, as well as setting the port to 3306. I don't think that worked, as after restarting MySQL, the port was still set to 3307.

Comment: Have you uncommented the  bind-address directive in your mysql config file: my.cnf ?

Comment: Well, since you connected with the user root on the console, have you tried to use it as a connection user and password on your configuration?

Comment: Also, did you created the user pankaj on the mysql ? have you tried to connect with it on the mysql console ?

Comment: Where would the my.cnf be on OS X?

Comment: I created a my.cnf filling the instructions here, and restarted the MySQL service. And no dice.

Comment: The password is actually lowercase in the file. I had to go back and edit my post with my phone and auto-correct thought it was being super helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this from first principles.

The JDBC URL you are using, which says that you are trying to connect to "localhost:3307"

The `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` means that the database was not listening for requests on the IP address and port number that your client was trying to use.

So why could be going wrong?

- It could be that the database simply wasn't running, but you have probably eliminated that.  (You can run the `mysql` client from the command line?)
- It could be that you (or someone) has misguidedly configured `localhost` to resolve to something other than `127.0.0.1`.  (Some people do crazy things ...)
- But I think that the most likely explanation is that MySQL is not listening for requests 127.0.0.1.

One way to be sure of this is to start the database, and then run "netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep tcp".  That will show you all of the IP addresses and port numbers that are currently being "listened" on.  Make sure that the address/port combination you are trying to use is included.

(Note that an IPv4 address `0.0.0.0` means any address.  It is a wildcard.)

Once you have figure out what the server is listening on you can decide between changing the JDBC URL to match that, or getting the server to listen on the IP / port you want to use.

---

Other people are suggesting a problem with user-names and passwords.  These suggestions are red herrings.  If that was the problem, the exception would be different.

Comment: I double checked MySQL from the command line, and it is running. I can login using "mysql -u root -p". And I double checked the localhost and it is set to 127.0.0.1. Running the net stat command, first listing is listening on 127.0.0.1:3307. When I stop the MySQL service it is no longer listed. When I start it back up it is listed again. What is odd is I added /etc/my.cnf with only "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" and "port = 3306". Shouldn't that set the listening port to 3306?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem update `my.cnf` file search on :

`skip-networking`

and update it to be :

`#skip-networking`

finally restart `Mysql`

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure your MySql Server Service is Started, if not go to controlPanel -> Services and Search for **Mysql80** and start it.